# Drywall question... Difficult wall / tub transition

Tags: drywall, bathtub, tiling

So I'm trying to figure out what the best way to repair the transition area between my tub and the wall. Splashing from the shower has wrecked the wall and trim. I pried the trim away and it's rotted away so it looks like I'll need to remove some drywall for sure, but I'm not sure how to go about preventing this from happening again.

I know the shower tile is mounted to cement board. The adjoining wall is green board drywall.[image] The tile kind of hangs over the edge of the tub, and then the wall is set back about an inch for the edge of the tub. It really doesn't look great (even when it's not rotted). The picture shows the issue better than I can describe... Does anyone have any suggestions how this could be repaired and made to look right?

Comment: Especially in a bathroom, there should be a gap between the floor and the lower edge of the drywall. The spec is 1/4" minimum, but in the bathroom? Never short yourself in a land of plenty.

Answer (score 1):

To repair, the drywall and baseboard will have to be removed and any rotted material removed.  Cut the drywall back about 4 or 5 inches. Any other details will have to be determined after the wall is opened.

What you need to prevent water damage in the future is [splash guards](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Prime-Line-10-3-4-in-White-Plastic-Curved-Splash-Guard-Accessory-Set-for-Bathtubs-1-pair-M-6086/202636493?g_store=&source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&pla&mtc=SHOPPING-BF-ARM-GGL-Multi-Multi-NA-NA-NA-PLALIA-NA-RKT-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-ALL_IN_TEST_THRIFTTRAD&cm_mmc=SHOPPING-BF-ARM-GGL-Multi-Multi-NA-NA-NA-PLALIA-NA-RKT-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-ALL_IN_TEST_THRIFTTRAD-71700000110012104-58700008378060415-92700076247464081&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAiA04arBhAkEiwAuNOsIojgj1LOB-8-T3ATZkXgnPf_YaqmubZ0C-0jfHzwXazVW9Hcaip4exoC6bwQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds).

It is common for water from a shower to sneak past a curtain and run down the side of the tub. The splash guards or a glass enclosure is the only way to prevent this.

Comment: Ah, I haven't seen those splash guards before. I will need to pick one up. Any thoughts on making the transition from above look better? I was thinking something maybe like "J Bead" on the edge of the drywall, and then I could bring it out flush with where the tile ends. Not sure if that would be asking for trouble overlapping the tub by an inch though. I'd also need to fill the rounded part on the edge of the tub with grout or something. Not sure what to do with that, just thinking out loud.

Comment: When doing the repair, I would seal the edge between the tub and any tile or drywall with polyurethane caulk. . Fill the tub corner with grout.  When I tile around a tub, I have the tile extend at least 2 inches past the front edge and tile to the floor.

Comment: Personally, I'd get some PVC "lumber" and trim it to fit so that it's flush with the painted wall, and the tile wall.  Then glue it in place, and finish with hot mud and paint to match the wall.  Use some caulk where the rounded edge of the tub creates a void.  If you can find a suitable narrow tile that looks like with the tiled wall, run a line up the wall.

Comment: That's a great idea with the pvc lumber. I was contemplating replacing that piece with cement board, but attaching over the tub was concerning due to potential movement. PVC 'lumber' should hold to the tub with some adhesive and also fit the waterproof requirement. I think I have some tile that matches, but that strip is just the edge of a piece of drywall in thickness, so it's only 1/2" wide. Still, I suppose that may look better than a painted edge.